# Return CDF (as a function) given a vector of values and their corresponding probabilities

Tags: r, probability

Consider the following simplified example:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
p <- rep(1, times = 3)/3
```

This indicates that I have a discrete probability distribution with probability `1/3` assigned to each of `1`, `2`, and `3`. You may assume that `x` and `p` have been ordered appropriately as above (i.e., each component of `x` has corresponding probability in `p`), with `x` in ascending order as above. You should **not** assume that `x` only takes on integer values, and you should **not** assume that `p` is identical in every component. In my actual problem, `x` and `p` can be vectors with length of approximately `100`.

I would like to output a **function** (not a graph, like what I have seen from other examples) which outputs values equal to the cumulative distribution function of the probability mass function given above in R, using **only** `x` and `p`.

---

For the probability background: if you're not familiar with probability, the cumulative distribution function is the probability that you obtain a value less than or equal to a certain value. Let's call this "certain value" `t`.

If I give you any value `t < 1`, then based on the example above, the cumulative distribution function should output `0`, since no probabilities are assigned to values less than `1`.

Suppose I give you a value `t` satisfying `t >= 1` and `t < 2`. Then in this interval, one has that the probability assigned to `1` is `1/3`, hence for `t >= 1` and `t < 2`, the cumulative distribution function should output `1/3`.

If `t >= 2` and `t < 3`, up to this point, based on the prior discussion, we have a probability of `1/3` from the prior step, as well as a probability of `1/3` at `t = 2`. Hence, if `t >= 2` and `t < 3`, the cumulative distribution function should output `2/3`.

If `t >= 3`, the cumulative distribution function should output `1`.

---

We could theoretically code this function out as follows and have `t` be the only argument:

```
x_cdf <- function(t) {
  if (t < 1) {
    return(0)
  }
  if (t >= 1 & t < 2) {
    return(1/3)
  }
  if (t >= 2 & t < 3) {
    return(2/3)
  }
  if (t >= 3) {
    return(1)
  }
}
```

However, the difficulty here, from my perspective, is generating the `if` statements based on the vectors `x` and `p`.

To re-emphasize: the CDF should only depend on `t` as an argument, and should be readily generated from `x` and `p`. It is necessary that `t` be allowed to be a value that is **NOT** in the vector `x`.

---

## Pseudocode of what I think I'm looking for:

```
generate_cdf <- function(x, p) {
  cdf <- function(t) {
    # some stuff here that depends on x and p that I'm not sure how to code
  }
  return(cdf)
}
```

Comment: The built-in `ecdf` function does this for raw data (not with weights/probabilities). You could probably base your function off that one, or rely on it internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically there.

Put this in the function body you are creating:

```
sum( p[ x <= t ] )
```

```r
generate_cdf <- function(x, p) {
    cdf <- function(t) {
        sum( p[ x <= t ] )
    }
    return(cdf)
}

f <- generate_cdf(x, p)

cbind( 0:4, sapply( 0:4, f ) )
```

Outputs:

```
> cbind( 0:4, sapply( 0:4, f ) )
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,]    0 0.0000000
[2,]    1 0.3333333
[3,]    2 0.6666667
[4,]    3 1.0000000
[5,]    4 1.0000000
```

#### Vectorize

For added finesse, you might [Vectorize](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Vectorize) it also, letting it process multiple values in one go:

```r
generate_cdf <- function(x, p) {
    cdf <- function(t) {
        sum( p[ x <= t ] )
    }
    return(Vectorize(cdf))
}

f <- generate_cdf(x, p)

f( c(1,2) ) # outputs [1] 0.3333333 0.6666667
```